# Optimize the following sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to optimize the below SQL query but I am stuck with subquery inside select clause.

```
select  F.id,

  (select top 1 RF1.gid from t_RemFinding RF1 where RF1.id = RF.id and RF1.active = 1) as GI

   from t_Finding F                             
   left join t_RemFinding RF on RF.id = F.id
   where F.Gid = '1001'
```

Could anyone explain me how does select sub query in select clause is working. I guess, the subquery is running for every iteration on the outer query. Is that right? Can I optimize it? If so, can you guide me the way. Thank you

**EDIT**

If the tb_RemFinding is already used in left join why the same table is being used inside select sub query and matching the same tables. Any help is greatly appreciated. The query is written by some other developer and I am trying to rewrite it.

Comment: TOP but no ORDER BY. How come? Skip sub-query, do a left join instead.

Comment: We are starving execution plans!

Comment: @jarlh that was some old code, i could not figure out what they did without order by. I was confused what the query is actually doing and how do I  do left join because table is already joined in left join??

Comment: Why you need this condition inside subquery where RF1.id = RF.id as you join condition is already there. Remove unnecessary condition and if you provide the indexing strategy for t_finding and t_RemFinding will be useful

Comment: @KannanKandasamy that query was written by some one else i want it to be updated with new sql code

Comment: would you add table structure and some sample data please? is `id` primary key in  `t_RemFinding` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that you don't want the `join` in the outer query:

```
select F.id,
       (select top 1 RF1.gid
        from t_RemFinding RF1
        where RF1.id = F.id and RF1.active = 1
       ) as GI
from t_Finding F                             
where F.Gid = 1001 ;  -- removed the single quotes
```

Assuming that `F.Gid` is a number, don't use single quotes around the constant.

Then, you want two indexes:  `t_Finding(Gid, id)` and `t_RemFinding(id, active, gid)`.

I also note the lack of `ORDER BY` clause with `TOP`.  That usually indicates a problem.  Sometimes, though, you just want *any* arbitrary value, so it depends on the intention of the query.

Comment: If i remove the left join, the alias RF goes unfound. could you please check

Comment: Does it produce the same results? With OP's query you receive `t_Finding x t_RemFinding` rows with count column. This produces `t_Finding` rows.

Comment: @PawełDyl . . . That is exactly the point.  I don't think the OP wants all those duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

At every iteration your subquery is run again, indeed. The best you can do now is a multiple index on t_RemFinding over the fields id, active

Although a TOP 1 without specifying and order doesn't make much sense (it could take whatever record it wants that fulfills its conditions).

It should probably better be something like :

```
select  F.id,

  (select top 1 RF1.gid from t_RemFinding RF1 where RF1.id = RF.id and RF1.active = 1 order by RF1.gid desc) as GI

   from t_Finding F                             
   left join t_RemFinding RF on RF.id = F.id
   where F.Gid = '1001'
```

And you can now optimize it better with a multiple index on t_RemFinding over id, active, gid

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to completely eliminate the sub query and use just joins? can i rewrite the query

Answer (score 0):

Use **PartitionBy**:

```
select
    X.id,
    X.gid as GI
from
(
    select  
        F.id,
        RF.gid as GI,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY RF.id ORDER BY RF.gid) AS PartNo
    from t_Finding F                             
    left join t_RemFinding RF on RF.id = F.id
        AND RF.active = 1
    where F.Gid = '1001' 
)X
where X.PartNo=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Outer Apply** operator.

```
   SELECT  F.id,t.gid
   FROM t_Finding a
    OUTER APPLY (select top 1 b.gid from t_RemFinding b where b.id = a.id and b.active = 1)t
    WHERE F.Gid = '1001'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY as well and you can check active status in the where clause if want only active from whole query.

```
SELECT RF.id, GI.gid  
FROM t_Finding RF
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RF1.gid 
             FROM t_RemFinding RF1 
             WHERE RF1.id = RF.id AND RF1.active = 1 
             ORDER BY RF1.id DESC) AS GI
WHERE RF.Gid = '1001'
```

Answer (score 0):

It hard to answer this question without some example data for the tables and what the output is supposed to look like. Looking at the query it would seem that the query attempts to return the “gid” ID but only for records that is still active `RF1.Active = 1`. If this is correct then a simple case statement should do the job.

```
SELECT  F.id,
        ( 
            CASE
                WHEN RF.active = 1 THEN RF.gid
                ELSE NULL
             END
        ) AS GI
FROM t_Finding F                             
LEFT JOIN t_RemFinding RF on RF.id = F.id
WHERE F.Gid = '1001'
```